# ffmpeg - how can I make a video out of video given a list of frames?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a list of frames `frames = [23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 345, 346, 347]` and a video file `input.mp4` recorded at 100 fps.

Could someone show me how to make a video `output.mp4` taking only frames from `frames`?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [select](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) and [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='eq(n,23)+eq(n,25)+eq(n,26)+eq(n,26)+eq(n,27)+eq(n,28)+eq(n,346)+eq(n,347)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" output.mp4
```